Change font color on selected file in JetBrains IDE
How to change the color of the name of selected file in JetBrains IDEs like Rider and such?

The closest setting to that I found was in "Version Control > File Status Colors".
I hope to find a way to change this without entirely switch the theme.

That color comes from a Theme. AFAIK there is no style in a GUI to change that (although some themes/plugins like Material Theme UI allow changing some of the theme-originated styles via their UI) . Themes: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/themes-getting-started.html
